# Updating an Angular PWA in a controlled manner: Questions

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, service-worker-events

I've been playing around with angular's PWA. I got everything running as I wanted, but I still have some unanswered questions:

- The swUpdate.available observable randomly fires twice (at once). How come?
- What if I prompt the user with a dialog when an update is available, but he declines - will swUpdate.available ever fire again?
- Calling swUpdate.checkForUpdate() sometimes takes under 100ms, and sometimes a really long time (+90sec). What can be the cause?
- Finally, when opening my app (with PWA) the first time, the initial load often takes a long time (+10 sec), although I am using registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately'.

I find the swUpdate API to be a bit archaic. Why does checkForUpdate() not return an Observable with the UpdateAvailableEvent if there is any? ‍♂️

Cheers

Comment: I posted this feature request: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/40467

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could not fix this problem, I switched to [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox)